# WooCommerce: Disable product loop without touching the template

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I want to remove the product loop on some archive pages.
In my case if the current archive is a vendor archive. But I guess the why isn't too important.

At the moment I'm using a custom `archive-product.php`.
I added and if/else condition around this part of the template code:

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
```

It works but I had to edit the theme file.

I saw that there is an if/else for the loop itself:

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {
```

Can I hook this part to disable the loop without touching the `archive-product.php`?

Comment: What `theme` file? Woocommerce specifically has template files like `archive-product.php` that you can put into your child theme so you can modify it. That's the point of templates.

Comment: That's exactly the one, as I wrote in my question. But I find a hook cleaner and more future proof

Comment: Templates and hooks would both suffer from future updates from WC if they were to change it. There isn't, at least to my knowledge, a hook to remove the loop. You could use a `pre_get_posts` filter to check if it's the archive and has the term and return 0 results - but the template is probably your best option.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: you can use woocommerce_product_query hook

Comment: Ah thanks. I will look into that